# element click intercepted error while automating Angular using Protractor/Java script

Tags: angular, protractor

Im getting the following error while clicking a button:
Failed: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1383, 73). Other element would receive the click: ...

Code:
describe('Successful login of xyz application', function () {

```
it('Launching Application', function () {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); 
    var menuButton = element(by.xpath('//span[.="Today"]'));
    browser.get('xyz-url')
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    console.log('Beta Application launched successfully')
    browser.sleep(8000)

    menuButton.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
});
```

})

Comment: Try clicking the element's parent instead.

Comment: I tried clicking the parent element aswell, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is several issues for that. I usually try to wait element to be clickable or click it using javascript.

```
static readonly EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(menuButton);
menuButton.click();
```

or

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', menuButton);
```